# Use regex to match URL up to the last forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to extract the value from:

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/one/two/three/file.png"/>"https://www.google.com/one/file.jpg"
```

to:

"https://www.google.com/one/two/three/"
"https://www.google.com/one/"

I basically want to capture everything in the base url to the last forward slash.

I've tried using `/https://([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/` which captures the entire url but I can't figure out how to stop the match at the last '/' of the URL in the html file

Answer (score 1):

Try split split() method, this make your problem much more simpler

```
function str(str_url){
 var arr = str_url.split('/');   //splits url at every '/'
 arr.pop();    //this pops the last term in url
 str_url = arr.join('/');    //finally joins everything 
 return str_url;
}
```

Read more about it at [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 1):

If your are sure about the format, you could use:

```
https?:\/\/[^/"]+([^/"]+\/)+
```

Where

- `https?:\/\/[^/"]+` matches `https://` and everything up to the first `/` and
- `([^/"]+\/)+` matches one or more instances of `abc/`

See also: https://regex101.com/r/6ohuWP/1